# merge two dictionaries Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, merge

This is kind-of related to this question, on how to merge two dictionaries in C#. An elegant Linq solution is presented, which is cool.

However, that question relates to `Dictionary<Object1, Object2>`, whereas I have a dictionary where the value is a  `Dictionary<string, Object>`.

I am looking for a solution for merging tow `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Object>>`, with the following requirements:

- Without duplicating key in the dictionary result of two dictionary,
- For each dictionary I think a grouping by KEY can be part of the solution but after ...

  ```
  internal static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> OperationDic(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> a, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> b, string operation)`
      { 
          switch (operation) 
          {
              case "+":
                  var result =  a.Concat(b).GroupBy(d => d.Key).ToDictionary (d => d.Key, d => d.First().Value); 
                  return result;               
              default: 

                  throw new Exception("Fail ...");
          }             
      }
  ```

Comment: already I'm stuck and I tried anything yet I'm still looking

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we can expand on it.

Comment: @Ks_Hamza: You should use `ToLookup` rather than `ToDictionary`.

Comment: @Ks_Hamza: `a.Concat(b).ToLookup(c => c.Key, c => c.Value)` (i think)

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear to me what you want. This tries to merge the two dictionaries:

```
    // first copy everything from a
    var result = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>(a);

    // now check to see if we can add stuff from b
    foreach (var entryOuter in b)
    {
      Dictionary<string, object> existingValue;
      if (result.TryGetValue(entryOuter.Key, out existingValue))
      {
        // there's already an entry, see if we can add to it
        foreach (var entryInner in entryOuter.Value)
        {
          if (existingValue.ContainsKey(entryInner.Key))
            throw new Exception("How can I merge two objects? Giving up.");
          existingValue.Add(entryInner.Key, entryInner.Value);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        // new entry
        result.Add(entryOuter.Key, entryOuter.Value);
      }
    }

    return result;
```

You might want to add checks for `null`. `a`, `b`, and `existingValue` (when it exists) may be `null`.

Comment: `throw new Exception("How can I merge two objects? Giving up.")` - Nice try. I think this is exactly what has been asked here.

Comment: @pescolino If an "outer" key of `a` is identical to an "outer" key of `b`, the two corresponding values are dictionaries. As you see I merge them. But when these two dictionaries share an "inner" key, the inner values are of type `object`. There's no way to merge two general objects. To do that, one would have to require something additional, e.g. change the type `object` to a new type `IMergeable` where the `IMergeable` interface should provide a method for merging with another object.

Comment: this may be a solution to my request but am looking for a solution without lopping just linq

Answer (score 0):

try this

var result = a.Concat(b).GroupBy(c => c.Key).ToDictionary>(

Answer (score 0):

```
 internal static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> OperationDic(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> a, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> b, string operation)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>(a);
        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":                  
            // now check to see if we can add stuff from b
            foreach (var entryOuter in b)
            {
              Dictionary<string, object> existingValue;
              if (result.TryGetValue(entryOuter.Key, out existingValue))
              {
                  Dictionary<string, object> Value = entryOuter.Value;
                  result[entryOuter.Key] = existingValue.Concat(Value).GroupBy(d => d.Key).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.First().Value);
              }
              else
              {
                // new entry
                result.Add(entryOuter.Key, entryOuter.Value);
              }
            }
            return result;
            default:                    
                throw new Exception("FAIL ...");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question you should ask yourself: What type does the result of merging two dictionaries have? How can values be merged together if they share the same key?

It could be something like this:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> Merge<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> this_, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> other)
{
    return this_.Concat(other).     // IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
        GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key).    // grouped by the keys
        ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).Distinct());
}
```

So your two dictionaries of type `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>` will go to a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>`.

However, your values are dictionaries so you might want to merge them:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TValue>> Flatten<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>> dictionaries)
{
    return dictionaries.SelectMany(d => d.Keys).Distinct().         // IEnumerable<TKey> containing all the keys
        ToDictionary(key => key,
            key => dictionaries.Where(d => d.ContainsKey(key)).     // find Dictionaries that contain the key
                Select(d => d.First(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(key))).   // select that key (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)
                Select(kvp => kvp.Value));                          // and the value
}
```

This takes an `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` and transforms it into a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>`. You can now call this method for each value of the dictionary that `Merge` produced.

The calls would be:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>> result1 = dic1.Merge(dic2);
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>> result2 = dic1.Merge(dic2).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => Flatten(kvp.Value));
```